# Python re.findall prints output as list instead of string

Tags: python, regex, findall

My re.findall search is matching and returning the right string, but when I try to print the result, it prints it as a list instead of a string.  Example below:

```
> line =  ID=id5;Parent=rna1;Dbxref=GeneID:653635,Genbank:NR_024540.1,HGNC:38034;gbkey=misc_RNA;gene=WASH7P;product=WAS protein family homolog 7 pseudogene;transcript_id=NR_024540.1

> print re.findall(r'gene=[^;\n]+', line)

>     ['gene=WASH7P']
```

I would like the print function just to return `gene=WASH7P` without the brackets and parentheses around it.

How can I adjust my code so that it prints just the match, without the brackets and parentheses around it?

Thank you!

Comment: `print re.findall(r'Name=[^;]+', line)[0]` should do the trick.

Comment: Are you expecting more than one match? If not - use `re.search` instead

Comment: Both of those suggestions worked on a couple of my regular expressions, however, they are not working for another regex in my script.  print re.findall(r'Name=[^;]+', line)[0] returns an error that "list index is out of range" and using print re.search().group returns an error of 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.    I have checked that the regex is finding the intended string and it prints the result if I just do print re.findall() but it prints the output as a list .  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: @Ilea Impossible. If re.search is returning NoneType, then there is no match. Show your code please, including the line.

Comment: Update your question including info from your comment in it.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry - I too thought this was impossible - so I was stumped by  that result.  I just figured out why that was happening (explained in my answer).

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for everyone's help!

Both of the below codes were successful in printing the output as a string.

```
> re.findall(r'gene=[^;\n]+', line)[0]  

> re.search(r'gene=[^;\n]+', line).group
```

However, I was continuing to get "list index out of range" errors on one of my regex, even though results were printing when I just used re.findall().

```
> re.findall(r'transcript_id=[^\s]+',line)
```

I realized that this seemingly impossible result was because I was calling re.findall() within a **for** loop that was iterating over every line in a file.  There were matches for some lines but not for others, so I was receiving the "list index out of range" error for those lines in which there was no match.

the code below resolved the issue:

```
> if re.findall(r'transcript_id=[^\s]+',line):

>    transcript = re.findall(r'transcript_id=[^\s]+',line)[0]

> else:

>   transcript = "NA"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It prints it as a list, because.. it is a list.

[findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a **list** of strings.

To print only the string use `print(re.findall(r'Name=[^;]+', line)[0])` instead.

That code is assuming you do have one match. If you have 0 matches, you ll get an error. If you have more, you ll print only the first match.

To ensure you are not getting an error, check if a match was found before you use `[0]` (or `.group()` for `re.search()`).

```
s = re.search(r'Name=[^;]+', my_str)
if s:
    print(s.group())
```

or `print(s[0])`

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are getting could be because your regex is not returning any match for the findall function.Please try to check what is the return type of the object returned by **re.findall** before trying to index it.Use this code before indexing so that if list is empty it will not raise indexerror.

```
x = re.findall(r'Name=[^;]+', line)
if not len(x):
    #write your logic
```